# How to link a WSDL file in a SOAP request in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, soap, wsdl

The WSDL describes features of how to access and retrieve information from a site. I want to make a SOAP request in JavaScript and need to link to this file. I have the link to the WSDL file. But where and how do I link the WSDL file in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a Javascript SOAP client, you have to read the WSDL and create the proxy class based on it.

Here you got a detailed tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12816/JavaScript-SOAP-Client